# g++ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I im writing sqlite3 wrapper with class to read db file. I im using ubuntu 64-bit and g++ compiler...and when i run code above i get this:

```
g++ ezserver.cpp -lsqlite3 -o ezserver
ezserver.cpp: In function int main():
ezserver.cpp:7:2: error: DataBase was not declared in this scope
DataBase = new EZServer();
^
```

database.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

/* LIBRARY */
#include <sqlite3.h>

/* CLASS */
class EZServer {
    public:
       EZServer();
      ~EZServer();

      int OpenDataBase(const char *TFileName);
      int CreateDataBase(const char *TFileName);

    private:
      sqlite3 *DataBase;
      sqlite3_stmt *QueryHandle[2];
};

#endif
```

database.cpp

```
#include "database.h"

/* CONSTRUCTOR */
EZServer::EZServer(): DataBase(0) {
    QueryHandle[0] = NULL;
    QueryHandle[1] = NULL;
}

/* DESTRUCTOR */
EZServer::~EZServer() {
    /* CLOSE - database */
    if (DataBase) {
        sqlite3_close(DataBase);
    }
}

/* LOAD - database file */
int EZServer::OpenDataBase(const char *TFileName) {
    /* OPEN - database */
    int Result = sqlite3_open_v2(TFileName, &DataBase, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);

    /* CHECK - database */
    if (Result != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("OpenDataBase: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(DataBase));
        sqlite3_close(DataBase);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/* CREATE - database file */
int EZServer::CreateDataBase(const char *TFileName) {
    /* OPEN - database */
    int Result = sqlite3_open_v2(TFileName, %DataBase, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

    /* CHECK - database */
    if (Result != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("OpenDataBaseCreate: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(DataBase));
        sqlite3_close(DataBase);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

ezserver.h

```
#ifndef EZSERVER_H
#define EZSERVER_H

/* FORWARD - declarations */
class EZServer;

/* CLASS */
class StatsClass {
    public:
        int Init();

    private:
        EZServer *DataBase;
};

#endif
```

ezserver.cpp

```
#include "ezserver.h"
#include "database.h"

int main() {
    DataBase = new EZServer();
}
```

main file is ezserver.cpp.
i im beginner in c++ so i read posts here try solutions but always get DataBase was not declared in this scope...could some one give solution?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I need to call EZServer() class name that holds functions like OpenDataBase CreateDataBase.

```
// Load database that opens save and query
Database = new EZServer();

Database->OpenDatabase("ezserver.db");
```

so i need this above ->OpenDataBase to be called from EZServer.cpp (main file program) and return from class EZServer value that function is defined in database.cpp

Comment: DataBase = new EZServer(); what is it?

Comment: You wanna initialize "EZServer *DataBase;" from StatsClass?

Comment: This is a pointer...i need this pointer DataBase to EZServer() class that holds functions...so i update above question for what it needs to be declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another problem, you should compile all *.cpp files.

```
g++ ezserver.cpp database.cpp -lsqlite3 -o ezserver
```

here is log when i run this:

- > g++ ezserver.cpp database.cpp -lsqlite3 -o ezserver database.cpp:4:20:
  >   error: definition of implicitly-declared â€˜EZServer::EZServer()â€™
  >   EZServer::EZServer(): DataBase(0) { ^ database.cpp:10:21: error:
  >   definition of implicitly-declared â€˜EZServer::~EZServer()â€™
  >   EZServer::~EZServer() { ^ database.cpp: In member function â€˜int
  >   EZServer::OpenDataBase(const char*)â€™: database.cpp:20:76: error:
  >   â€˜NULLâ€™ was not declared in this scope int Result =
  >   sqlite3_open_v2(TFileName, &DataBase, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL); ^
  >   database.cpp:24:56: error: â€˜printfâ€™ was not declared in this scope
  >   printf("OpenDataBase: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(DataBase)); ^
  >   database.cpp: In member function â€˜int EZServer::CreateDataBase(const
  >   char*)â€™: database.cpp:34:42: error: expected primary-expression
  >   before â€˜%â€™ token int Result = sqlite3_open_v2(TFileName,
  >   %DataBase, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL); ^
  >   database.cpp:34:97: error: â€˜NULLâ€™ was not declared in this scope
  >   int Result = sqlite3_open_v2(TFileName, %DataBase,
  >   SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL); ^
  >   database.cpp:38:62: error: â€˜printfâ€™ was not declared in this scope
  >
  > ### printf("OpenDataBaseCreate: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(DataBase)); ^

Comment: add
     #include <stdio.h>

Comment: I added same message...can you please copy paste above code and compile on linux machine? i think that way you will easy spot mistake

Comment: I compiled it and i haven't such error messages, are you sure that you have "database.h" and "database.cpp" in the same directory?

Comment: int Result = sqlite3_open_v2(TFileName, %DataBase, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL); // replace % to & in this line too

Comment: i just remove /* CONSTRUCTOR */
EZServer::EZServer(): DataBase(0) {
    QueryHandle[0] = NULL;
    QueryHandle[1] = NULL;
}

/* DESTRUCTOR */
EZServer::~EZServer() {
    /* CLOSE - database */
    if (DataBase) {
        sqlite3_close(DataBase);
    }
}
 and compile as you suggested above and all it works...thanks for helping:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write something like this:

```
EZServer* dataBase = new EZServer();
dataBase->OpenDataBase("ezserver.db");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer now error is this: ezserver.cpp:6:11: error: class EZServer has no member named OpenDatabase
 dataBase->OpenDatabase("ezserver.db"); so form this error i think i somewhere wrong define class...

Comment: I just copy your line "Database->OpenDatabase("ezserver.db");"

Comment: Yes you are right but i im getting message at compile that class EZServer has no member named OpenDataBase so if you can please check database.cpp and database.h files above where i im doing wrong? I im new to c++ so classes is confusing me because i think i defined it wrong

Comment: Your EZServer class definition above contain method OpenDataBase, check case. Or give me a full error log from compiler.

Comment: I run first line of your answer and this is from g++ log:    g++ ezserver.cpp -o ezserver
/tmp/ccuLJbCi.o: In function `main':
ezserver.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `EZServer::EZServer()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status